# command line - remove directory with contents without deleting contents

Tags: shell, command-line

Imagine my directory structure is like this:

```
Dir1 -> Dir2 -> {file1, Dir3, file2, Dir4, file3}
```

How do I delete `Dir1` from the command line without deleting all of the contents?

So the new structure would just be:

```
Dir2 -> {file1, Dir3, file2, Dir4, file3}
```

Comment: Try checking https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395182/delete-the-parent-folder-keeping-all-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `mv` command

```
cd Dir1
mv Dir2 ../
cd ../
ls
rmdir Dir1
```

I would verify with the ls command that your Dir2 was in fact moved before removing the Dir1

Comment: thank you. This is correct except first line should read `cd Dir1` instead of `Dir2`

Comment: nice catch. I've modified the answer.